# VectorPlot and VectorPlot3D showing blank output

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, version-12.1

I am trying to plot the following simple vector field
$$\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2-z^2}*(y,-x,0)$$
but when I plug this field into the functions `VectorPlot` and `VectorPlot3D`, the output graph is completely blank. The MWE im using is

```
ClearAll[expr]
expr[x_, y_, z_] := 
 N@Piecewise[{{Sqrt[4 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)] {y, -x, 0}, 
     4 > (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}}, {0, 0, 0}]
VectorPlot[expr[x, y, 0], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
VectorPlot3D[
 Evaluate@expr[x, y, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 VectorPoints -> Fine]
```

with output:

[image] [image]

which is no good :(.

I tried defining my vector field using the `ConditionalExpression` function:

```
ClearAll[expr]
field = Sqrt[4 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)] {y, -x, 0}
expr[a_, b_, c_] := 
 ConditionalExpression[field, Im[field] == {0, 0, 0}] /. {x -> a, 
   y -> b, z -> c}
expr[4, 4, 4]
VectorPlot3D[expr[x, y, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 VectorPoints -> Fine]
```

Now, this actually produces *something*, but its largely nonsense (even though it contains what Im looking for):

Undefined

[image]

I entered  `expr[4,4,4]` to verify it returns undefined, as it should. However, `VectorPlot3D` is still plotting something. I don't even know what it could be plotting in the area where it should be empty.
Perhaps Mathematica is doing something strange and somehow evaluating the imaginary part and then plotting it? I really don't know.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `RegionFunction` instead of `Piecewise`

```
VectorPlot3D[Sqrt[4 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)] {y, -x, 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,2}, {z, -2, 2}  
, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 4 > (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)],VectorPoints -> Fine]
```

[image]

or alternatively `Boole`

```
VectorPlot3D[Boole[4 > (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)] Sqrt[4 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)] {y, -x,0}
, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}  , VectorPoints -> Fine]
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!